# How to copy value in clipboard to a variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file, clipboard

I have a string in clip, and I want to copy it to a variable var.
I have to use that string to find further sub-strings in variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the functionality built into internet explorer, and use its clipboard object.  Then you can wrap up the VBScript which accesses the IE objects with a command script:

```
@ECHO OFF

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    CALL :GetClipboardText Text

    ECHO %LineCount% lines copied.

    ECHO Line1: %Text1%
    ECHO Line2: %Text2%
    ECHO Line3: %Text3%
    ECHO Line4: %Text4%

    ENDLOCAL

GOTO :EOF

:GetClipboardText

    CALL :GetTempFilename TempFile

    ECHO Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")>%TempFile%
    ECHO WScript.Echo objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")>>%TempFile%

    SET LineIndex=1

    FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('%TempFile% //NOLOGO') DO (
        SET %1!LineIndex!=%%A
        SET /A LineIndex=!LineIndex!+1
    )

    SET LineCount=%LineIndex%

    DEL %TempFile%

GOTO :EOF

:GetTempFilename

    FOR /F "delims=:. tokens=2-5" %%A IN ('ECHO ^| TIME') DO SET T=%%A%%B%%C%%D & GOTO :X

:X

    CALL :Trim %T% T

    SET %1=%Temp%\TMP%T%.vbs

GOTO :EOF

:Trim
    SET %2=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the command script engine, I have to split up the text into lines.  In my example, %LineCount% will contain the number of lines, which will be retried by %Text1%, %Text2%, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Using The `clip` command
but  it don't exist in Windows XP :(

Comment: The `clip` command _stores_ text in the clipboard; does not _retrieve_ it...

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your operating system, toolkit, language. If you code in C++ with Qt on Linux, you could use [QClipboard::text](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qclipboard.html#text)

Answer (score 0):

Batch files can't directly interact with the clipboard. However, there are various people that have written little tools to do this for you, so you could get the `GetClip` tool from this [website](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/ConClip/).